# For a 2-dimensional random vector, express the probability of being in a rectangle in terms of CDF

Tags: probability, measure-theory

For $a_1\le b_1$ and $a_2\le b_2$, show that 
$$P\{ a_1<X_1\le b_1,a_2<X_2\le b_2 \}= F(a_1,a_2)+F(b_1,b_2)-F(b_1,a_2)-F(a_1,b_2)$$
Here $F(a,b)=P\{X_1\le a,\ X_2\le b\}$, the cumulative distribution function.

I know that I need to write down the probability of rectangle as a combination of four probabilities which then I would write down as distribution functions of F. But I don't know how.

Comment: Figured out myself: $P(X_1<=b_1,X_2<=b_2)+P(X_1<=a_1,X_2<=a_2)-P(X_1<=a_1,X_2<=b_2)-P(X_1<=b_1,X_2<=a_2)$                            =$F(a1,a2)+F(b1,b2)−F(b1,a2)−F(a1,b2)$

Comment: Use `\le` and `\ge` to get $\le$ and $\ge$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out myself: $P\{ a_1<X_1\le b_1,a_2<X_2\le b_2 \}$ can be written as 
$$P(X_1\le b_1,X_2\le b_2)+P(X_1\le a_1,X_2\le a_2)-P(X_1\le a_1,X_2\le b_2)-P(X_1\le b_1,X_2\le a_2)$$ which is equal to                           $$ F(a_1,a_2)+F(b_1,b_2)−F(b_1,a_2)−F(a_1,b_2)$$ -- [Justin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487744/for-a-2-dimensional-random-vector-express-the-probability-of-being-in-a-rectang#comment3031902_1487744)